# Is AudioKit support coming for iOS 12 anytime?

Tags: ios, xcode, audiokit

Since currently AudioKit only supports iOS 11, I would like to know if there's any update coming anytime sooner?

I'm currently working on an app which is iOS 12 compatible. Now I'm moving to programming audio using AudioKit, but it's not working so far. Really want to know if it's under works or not.

Comment: This is better suited as a question on that library's Github repo, which you have already asked [here](https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/issues/1487).

Answer (score 0):

I've addressed this on Github https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/issues/1487 but I will respond here as well.

As far as I can tell AudioKit is fully compatible with Mojave and iOS12.  I run them both on my test machines have seen no issues.  You do have build AudioKit from scratch on these systems, rather than using Cocoapods or a prebuilt binary.  When the Golden Masters come out, we'll update the Cocoapods and such, and definitely when the OS's come out of beta, we'll be on top of it.